# overfitting in dnn model

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a dataset on which I train a DNN model.
my dataset contain 398 samples and 330 features, i redueced features to 39 with ExtraTreeclassifier(). this my model :

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xfinal, val_y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=20, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu',input_dim=nb_features))
model.add(Dense(units=20, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=10, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=5, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1,kernel_initializer='uniform',activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data=(X_test,y_test),batch_size=32,epochs=250)
```

I tried Dropout but my model steel overfitting :
[image]

Any solution for my model ?

Comment: Remove all `kernel_initializer='uniform'` statements, the [default](https://keras.io/layers/core/) `glorot_uniform` works best.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `Dropout` layer between `Dense` layers like below.

```
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

Also you can remove one or more hidden layers from your architecture.

One more thing is, you can use `Earlystopping` method to stop at correct epoch number.

Your final model architecture can be like below:

```
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)]
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=20, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu',input_dim=nb_features))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=5, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1,kernel_initializer='uniform',activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data=(X_test,y_test),batch_size=32,epochs=250, callbacks=callbacks)
```